# How can I use python difflib to compare json objects with multiple fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, difflib

The desired outcome is for a JSON object to come in looking similar to the example below. From there the difflib would process both *DataToCompare* *name* and *address* to *DataSetAgainst* *name* and *address* and spit out the difference similiar to the JSON out example.

JSON in:

```
{
  "DataToCompare": [
    {
        "name": "Alex Young",
        "address": "123 Main Street"
    }
  ],
  "DataSetAgainst": [
    {
        "name": "Bob Doll",
        "address": "555 South Street"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bob Young",
        "adress": "123 Main St."
    }
  ]
}
```

JSON out:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Bob Doll",
        "Name Match": 11.8,
        "address": "555 South Street",
        "address match": <some number>
    },
    {
        "name": "Bob Young",
        "Name Match": 55.6,
        "address": "123 Main St.",
        "address match": <some number>
    }
]
```

Currently I get back "name" and "name match" but would also need to get the address diffs also. My python code looks as follows.

def fuzzy_request(dataIncoming):

```
data_to_compare = dataIncoming["DataToCompare"][0]
mt_name = data_to_compare['name']

dataList = []
for i in dataIncoming["DataSetAgainst"]:
    dataList.append(i["name"])

dataResults = []

for i in dataList:
    dataBack = {}
    clean_name = ''.join(e for e in i if e.isalnum())
    sequence = difflib.SequenceMatcher(isjunk=None, a=mt_name, b=clean_name)
    difference = sequence.ratio()*100
    difference = round(difference, 1)

    dataBack["name"] = i
    dataBack["Name Match"] = difference

    dataResults.append(dataBack)

return json.dumps(dataResults)
```

Comment: Basic put your *diff* part into a function, e.g. `diff(key):` and do `for key in ['name', 'address']:; diff_ = diff(key)`. **BTW**: You are comparing `'123 Main Street', '555SouthStreet'`, the **second** is cleaned with `.isalnum()` the **first** not!